# ios/xcode: How to trigger method from pressing table row in static table controller

Tags: ios, methods, tablerow

I had a page where the user clicked a button on a link and it triggered a private method(to display an action sheet).  To wire it up, all I did was control drag from the button to the method in the .m file.

However, I have now changed the button to a Settings-style static tableviewcontroller and I can't figure out or remember (as I think I have done this in the past) how to fire a method from pressing a row.  Control-dragging to the class only gives you the option of creating an outlet, not an action method.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Do your thing, i.e. call your method
}
```

Also make sure that you properly set a delegate property for your UITableView